# History of data which i searched is not saving in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I'm using Ajax to fetch records from API , when i click on search items , page get redirected to the book and author page. i want to store the record of that search.But it fails to store the data in mongoose .
Data is not saving.

My task is to list last 15 search which user search. and show on history page .Please help me guys

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Book Bank API</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script
            src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/corejs-typeahead/1.2.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>



</head>
<style>
    /* scaffolding */
    /* ----------- */
    .tt-menu,
    .gist {
        text-align: left;
    }
    /* base styles */
    /* ----------- */
    html {
        font: normal normal normal 18px/1.2 "Helvetica Neue", Roboto, "Segoe UI", Calibri, sans-serif;
        color: #292f33;
    }
    a {
        color: #03739c;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .table-of-contents li {
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
    }
    .table-of-contents li a {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #999;
    }
    p + p {
        margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    }
    /* site theme */
    /* ---------- */
    .title {
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;
        font-size: 64px;
    }
    .example {
        padding: 30px 0;
    }
    .example-name {
        margin: 20px 0;
        font-size: 32px;
    }
    .demo {
        position: relative;
        *z-index: 1;
        margin: 50px 0;
    }
    .typeahead,
    .tt-query,
    .tt-hint {
        width: 396px;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 30px;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        outline: none;
    }
    .typeahead {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    .typeahead:focus {
        border: 2px solid #0097cf;
    }
    .tt-query {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    }
    .tt-hint {
        color: #999
    }
    .tt-menu {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 12px 400px;
        padding: 8px 0;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }
    .tt-suggestion {
        padding: 3px 20px;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 24px;
    }
    .tt-suggestion:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #0097cf;
    }
    .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #0097cf;
    }
    .tt-suggestion p {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .gist {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    /* example specific styles */
    /* ----------------------- */
    #custom-templates .empty-message {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #multiple-datasets .league-name {
        margin: 0 20px 5px 20px;
        padding: 3px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    #scrollable-dropdown-menu .tt-menu {
        max-height: 150px;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    #rtl-support .tt-menu {
        text-align: right;
    }
    #multiple-datasets .search {
        margin: 0 20px 5px 20px;
        padding: 3px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
</style>
<style>
    .topnav-right {
        float: right;
    }
    body {
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    form.example input[type=text] {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 17px;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        float: left;
        height: 50px;
        width: 1000px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #f1f1f1;
        margin-left: 80px;
    }
</style>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand m-auto" href="#">Book Bank</a>
        </div>
        <div class="topnav-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav -align-left">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/history">Last 15 Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Logout</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <!--
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <b> Authors selected: </b>
            <ul id="authorlist"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <b> Books selected: </b>
            <ul id="booklist"></ul>
        </div>
-->
    &nbsp;
    <br>
    <br>

    <div id="multiple-datasets">
        <form class="example" action="#">
            <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Enter The Book Name to Search" name="search">
        </form>
    </div>

    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <h1 align="center">List of Science Book Records</h1>
        &nbsp;
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Author Name</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="mypanel">


        <script>
            $.getJSON('https://openlibrary.org/subjects/science.json', function(data) {
                var show_per_page = 2;
                var page= data.works.length;
                var number_page = Math.ceil(page/show_per_page);
                console.log(data)
                for (var i=1;i<data.works.length;i++)
                {
                    var akey = `${data.works[i].authors[0].key}`
                    var bkey =`${data.works[i].key}`
                    var text = `<tr><td><a href="/book${bkey}">${data.works[i].title}</a></td>
                        <td><a href="/author${akey}">${data.works[i].authors[0].name}</a></td>
                    <td>${data.works[i].subject[i]}</td></tr>`
                    $(".mypanel").append(text);

                }
            });

        </script>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</body>

<script>
    var books = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: 'http://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY',
            filter: function (searchResults) {
                return $.map(searchResults.docs, function (searchResults) {
                    //  console.log(searchResults.author_name);
                    // console.log("key is "+searchResults.key)
                    if (JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedBooks") == undefined || JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedBooks").indexOf(searchResults.title)) == -1)){
                        return {
                            title: searchResults.title,
                            key: searchResults.key,
                        };
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    var authorsList = [];
    var authors = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: 'http://openlibrary.org/search.json?author=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY',
            filter: function (searchResults) {
                return $.map(searchResults.docs, function (searchResults) {
                    if (searchResults.author_name !== undefined){
                        var author = searchResults.author_name.toString();
                    }
                    if (authorsList.indexOf(author) == -1) {
                        authorsList.push(author);
                        return {
                            author_key: searchResults.author_key,
                            author: author,
                        };
                    }
                });
            },
        }
    });
    $('#multiple-datasets .typeahead').typeahead({
            highlight: true
        },
        {
            display: 'title',
            source: books,
            templates: {
                header: '<h3 class="search">Books List</h3>'
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'authors',
            display: 'author',
            source: authors,
            templates: {
                header: '<h3 class="search">Authors List</h3>'
            }
        });
    $('#multiple-datasets').bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj, datum, name) {
        console.log(datum);
        if (name === 'authors'){
         var  request =  $.ajax({

             type: 'POST',
             data: {author: datum.author}
               });
            `${data.works[i].authors[0].key}`
               request.done(function (msg) {
                   window.location.href="/author/authors/" +datum.author_key[0];
               });
            request.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus) {
                alert("Request Failed"+textStatus);

            });
        }
        else
        {
            var  request =  $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: `http://localhost:9090/history`,
                data: {book: datum.title}
            });
            request.done(function (msg) {
                window.location.href="/book" +datum.key;
            });
            request.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus) {
                alert("Request Failed"+textStatus);

            });

        }

    });
</script>
</html>
```

Route Page

```
app.post('/history',(req,res)=>{

        console.log(req.body);
        res.sendStatus(201);
            const  newHistory = new History({
            books_searched: req.body
        });
                newHistory.save().then(savedPost=>{
        console.log("data saved");

         });
    });
```

Error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: History validation
>   failed: books_searched: Cast to String failed for value "{ book:
>   'Aldous Huxley' }" at path "books_searched"
>       at new ValidationError (C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:30:11)
>       at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1898:32)
>       at model.$set (C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:878:10)
>       at model._handleIndex (C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:688:14)
>       at model.$set (C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:645:22)
>       at model.Document (C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:112:12)
>       at model.Model (C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:69:12)
>       at new model (C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4344:13)
>       at app.post (C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book api\app\routes.js:73:33)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book
>   api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book
>   api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:\Users\shankar\first-app\book api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       (node:2832) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: Problem is with you r mongoose schema i guess,

Comment: yeah i type string, but data is object

Comment: It will work , always console your data type before inserting into the schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this route code and make  sure you are using object type in schema.

```
 app.post('/history',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendStatus(201);
        const  newHistory = new History({

        searched: req.body
    });
            newHistory.save().then(savedPost=>{
    console.log("data saved");

     }).catch((error)=>{
         console.log(error);
            })
});
```